# XMPP client with photo sharing?

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I've set up my XMPP client but I would like to add a feature that I don't know if the server (Openfire) would support.

Users would be able to post photos to share with their friend. As simple as that.
It would look like a Whatsapp + Instagram, I guess ?

So, is it possible with Openfire or another XMPP server ? If not, how can I possibly realize this ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is very much possible to share the images or any media files through XMPP. You just need to upload the particular file to a file server and share the URL of the uploaded file through openfire.

The receiver can use that URL and download the file from the file server. You can also have credentials for the file server which can be shared across clients to access the file server, to upload and download files.